# Flowbite React: how to get rid of this annoying border?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, flowbite

I'm using Flowbite React, an dit has a lot of great elements, but many interactive component get this really annoying border when clicked. How do you et rid of it? This turns a beautiful component to an ugly one, and I can't figure out how to change it.

In the example here I am trying to use the tabs. When looking at the theme at the bottom of the page, I see that the border comes from the "ring" property which is set to `focus:ring-4 focus:ring-cyan-300`. I've tried setting my items className to this: `className="ring-0 focus:ring-0 focus:ring-transparent"` but nothing gets overridden and the ring still shows up.

This is my entire component:

```
"use client";

import { Tabs } from "flowbite-react";
import {BsFillGrid3X2GapFill, BsFan} from 'react-icons/bs'
import { HiSignal } from "react-icons/hi2";

export default function ConfigureDeckTabs({
  onTabChange,
}: {
  onTabChange: (tab: number) => void;
}) {
  return (
    <Tabs.Group style="underline" onActiveTabChange={onTabChange} className="mt-2">
      <Tabs.Item
        active
        icon={BsFillGrid3X2GapFill}
        title="Panels"
        className="ring-0  focus:ring-transparent focus:ring-8"
      ></Tabs.Item>
      <Tabs.Item
        icon={BsFan}
        title="Fans"
        className="ring-0 focus:ring-0 focus:ring-transparent"
      ></Tabs.Item>
      <Tabs.Item
        icon={HiSignal}
        title="Sensors"
        className="ring-0 focus:ring-0 focus:ring-transparent"
      ></Tabs.Item>
    </Tabs.Group>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please create a reproducible demo of the about output so that people here can look into your problem.

Comment: maybe you need to use [these tabs](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/tabs/) and use state to render details  accordingly

Comment: @Usama thank you for the suggestion. It's not really a way to disable the border, but is indeed the approach I should take and have taken. With the "vanilla" tailwind I get the result I want now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

override the style by using CSS

```
.focus\:ring-cyan-300:focus {
  --tw-ring-opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Override the style by using CSS

```
* {
    --tw-ring-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 0) !important;
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35342196)

Comment: This is exacty what fixed that for me! Just add this to `globals.css`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution: I have overridden the default styling of the tabs to customize the appearance of the items. Below is an example demonstrating how I achieved this:

```
    <Tabs
  style='underline'
  className='mb-4 w-max md:w-full'
  theme={{
    tablist: {
      tabitem: {
        base: 'flex items-center justify-center p-4 text-sm font-medium first:ml-0 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:text-gray-400 disabled:dark:text-gray-500 focus:ring-0  focus:outline-none rounded-t-lg border-b-2 border-transparent text-gray-500 hover:border-gray-300 hover:text-gray-600',
      },
    },
  }}
>
  {tabItems.map((tab) => (
    <Tabs.Item
      key={tab.title}
      active={tab.isActive}
      icon={() => renderIcon(tab.icon)}
      title={tab.title}
    >
      <tab.component />
    </Tabs.Item>
  ))}
</Tabs>
```

you can see that in thet tabs componenet i have overided the tabitmes in theme property, i have specified focus:ring-0 you can remove it and it will work properly because it wont exisiste at all.

Comment: I can attest that this works!

Answer (score 0):

It is a box-shadow.
Maybe add the class "shadow-none".